# Stationary distribution on a partition of the state space?

Tags: markov-process, partitioning

I would like to use the following type of model and am wondering if someone could let me know if this technique has been studied before (I assume it has) and where to learn more about it?

The idea is simple. I have a Markov process with a possibly infinite state space S. I have a partition P of S into a finite number of sets. I would like to compute a "stationary" distribution over the "states" in P.

(Bad example removed)

**Example** Let S be the set of real numbers in [0,100). My Markov process is to take the current state (a real number) and add a Gaussian variable distributed with mean 50 and variance 25, and taking the result modulo 100. (E.g. -3 ---> 97.) Let P have two states: [0,50) and [50,100). I'd like to know the equivalent of the stationary distribution over P: the proportion of the time our state is in (0,50], and the proportion of the time it is in (50,100).

Is this problem in general well-defined? (Of course there may be no answer for some examples.) Is there a known way to approach these problems or anywhere I can find out more?

Thanks very much!

(Edit/PS also let me know if I should crosspost to a different stackexchange.)

Comment: you should look at [POMDPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_observable_Markov_decision_process) for some inspiration, plus [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2294/lumping-in-markov-process-with-absorbing-states) deals with a simpler case.

Comment: Unfortunately neither seems to quite match this setting, although they're both interesting/related. POMDPs seem so much more complicated than this that I'm sure someone has addressed this setting somewhere....

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? In particular, here are my questions: (**1**) There is no randomness in the process you describe. Is this intended? (**2**) Once you create a partition encompassing several states, the process is no longer Markov. In fact, I believe it's fairly easy to see that the transitions from one partition to the next would not even be a measurable process on the natural filtration induced by the observed states. So, what do you hope to show? (**3**) Are you interested in the particular example you gave, or something more general? In the latter case,.../...

Comment: .../...more detail would be needed. (**4**) Note that in your particular example, with no randomness, the state evolution is completely deterministic and for any sequence of visited states you will, at some point, in less than 100 steps return to a previously visited state. From that point on you'd simply move in a cycle, making the "distribution" over the partition easy to calculate. For example, if we start at 1, we get the sequence: 2  9  0  1  4 25 76 29  0 and henceforth you'd cycle through 0 1 4 24 76 and 29 in order. So, the distribution would be 5/6 on $[0,50)$ and 1/6 on $[50,99)$.

Comment: This works for any initial state and the infinite cycle traversed is determined completely by the initial state. One could inject randomness by starting at a random position, but this really doesn't change much.

Comment: Finally (apologies for the verbosity of my comments), you might look at some of the work of [Jim Propp](http://faculty.uml.edu/jpropp/), specifically his stuff on rotor routers. In some sense, they share some similarities with the deterministic processes you describe; but they're more complex.

Comment: Hi, @cardinal, thanks very much for your thought-out response. That's completely my fault for using a dumb example. I _am_ interested in the general, random case. I've edited to include an actually relevant example.

Comment: @cardinal -- >  "In fact, I believe it's fairly easy to see that the transitions from one partition to the next would not even be a measurable process on the natural filtration induced by the observed states." I don't know what this means: "natural filtration induced".... Can you point me to a text/site that explains this terminology?

Comment: If I were to try to describe my goal formally, I think I would say "to write down the steady-state distribution of time spent in states belonging to partition P_i of P." I know this can be done in specific cases. For example, take the trivial case where the partition of S is the set of singletons from S -- this is just the stationary distribution.

Comment: For another, take any Markov process with a well-defined stationary distribution over the states S. I can take an arbitrary partition of S and, for each partition, simply add up the probabilities for each state in that partition. I end up with something like the "total time" spent in that partition.... Hope this clarifies! Thanks again!!

Comment: PS. The reason this might be interesting is if S has a well-defined stationary distribution which is impossible to compute or extremely messy, but it has a clean partition P for which there is an elegant computation and result. Maybe.

Comment: A good reference to understand why the partition index does not define a Markov chain is [Kemeny and Snell's Finite Markov chains](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0387901922/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0387901922) where they introduce and study the concept of *lumpable Markov chains*.

Comment: @Xi'an -- Thanks! Looking up [lumpability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumpability), this seems like almost exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for. It does seem that lumpability is a bit stronger than what I need -- it seems to be a condition for actually defining a new Markov chain. I feel like I shouldn't have to define a Markov chain over collections of states in order to talk about the "stationary probability" of being inside one of these collections. So I think there is still more to ask. That is really helpful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make things clear: given a positive recurrent Markov chain $(X_t)$,

1. the sequence $Y_t = \mathbb{I}_A(X_t)$ is not a Markov chain in most cases (see Kemeny and Snell's [Finite Markov chains](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387901922));
2. the sequence $Y_t = \mathbb{I}_A(X_t)$ has a limiting/stationary distribution directly induced by the limiting/stationary distribution of the Markov chain $(X_t)$.

Comment: But is this all there is to the story? For example (excuse my ignorance), does my example Markov process above have a stationary distribution at all? I thought not, since we have a state for each real number and the limiting probability of being in any one state is zero. Yet by symmetry it seems "obvious" that about half the time we'll be in a state less than 50 and half the time we'll be in a state greater. So can $Y_t$ have a stationary distribution when $X_t$ does not? --Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid you are lacking the basic background in probability theory to envision such questions! A Markov chain on a continuous space may enjoy a stationary distribution because the reference measure is the Lebesgue measure. In your case, you are simulating a random walk modulo 100, therefore the limiting and stationary distribution is the uniform distribution on (0,100). Then apply Item 2 above.

Comment: OK, I see, thanks! However (though as you said, I am naive in this area), I have another example. Let my states be the integers. In state n, my transition is to add an integer distributed uniformly on [1,n]. There is no stationary distribution as $n \to \infty$, but if I partition P_1 = {the even integers} and P_2 = {the odds}, I should be able to say something interesting, possibly? (Again, thanks very much for the help.)

Comment: In this case, your Markov chain $(X_t)$ is *growing* with probability $1$, hence cannot be ergodic. It goes almost surely to $+\infty$. There is no conclusion to be drawn from $X_t$. On the other hand, depending on the parity of $n$ (it has to be *even*), $Y_t$ may be changing parity at random, either being odd or even with probability $1/2$ independently of $Y_{t-1}$, in which case there is a stationary distribution.

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess the confusing part is that $Y_t$ isn't really a Markov chain, but as long as the "stationary distribution" on $Y_t$ is well-defined, I think that answers my question.

Comment: Actually, in the above example $(Y_t)$ is a Markov chain. A special Markov chain with zero dependence but a Markov chain nonetheless!

Comment: Hm. I will have to think more about it!